# Simple Linear Regression issue in Python

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression

I have this data:

[image]

and I am trying to do a simple linear regression model on it.

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = df[['Date']] 
y = df['ACP Cleaning'] 

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

X_predict = [['2021-1-1']]
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
```

and this is my error:

> ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal
> numbers with dtype='numeric'

Comment: I am saying this with the kindest intentions possible: If you do not know anything about the simple underlying algebra of the thing, doing in Python is not going to get any easier. All variables in a regression need to be numeric to begin with. You are going to need to map those strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear Regression works with numbers, not strings.

You must pre-process your data in order to match the input of the model.

One way to do it is to parse the string and convert it to timestamp:

```
import datetime

def process_date(date_str):
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
  return d.timestamp()

X = df[['Date']].apply(process_date)
```

The same must be done to the data you want to predict.

**Update:** If your dataset's datatype is correct, then the problem is with the data you are trying to use for prediction (you cannot predict a string).

The following is a complete working example. Pay close attention to the processing done to  the `X_predict` variable.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='3A')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
print(df.head())

X = np.array(df['Date']).reshape(-1,1)
y = df['Val']

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

def process_date(date_str):
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
  # return array
  return [d.timestamp()]


X_predict = ['2021-1-1']
X_predict = list(map(process_date, X_predict))
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
y_predict
```

Returns:

```
        Date       Val
0 2015-12-31 -0.110503
1 2018-12-31 -0.621394
2 2021-12-31 -1.030068
3 2024-12-31  1.221146
4 2027-12-31 -0.327685

array([-2.6149628])
```

**Update:** I used your data to create a csv file:

```
Date,Val
1-1-2020, 90404.71
2-1-2020, 69904.71
...
```

And then I loaded with pandas. Everything looks good to me:

```
def process_date(date_str):
  # the date format is month-day-year
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y')
  return d.timestamp()

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(process_date)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
Date    Val
0   1.577848e+09    90404.710
1   1.580526e+09    69904.710
2   1.583032e+09    98934.112
3   1.585710e+09    77084.430
4   1.588302e+09    35877.420
```

Extracting features:

```
# must reshape 'cause we have only one feature
X = df['Date'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
y = df['Val'].to_numpy()
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Predicting:

```
X_predict = ['1-1-2021', '2-1-2021']
X_predict = np.array(list(map(process_date, X_predict)))
X_predict = X_predict.reshape(-1, 1)
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
y_predict
```

Output:

```
array([55492.2660361 , 53516.12292932])
```

This is a good prediction. You can use matplotlib to plot your data and  convince yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Val'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get this error when running the code:
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: @juge I updated my answer with a complete example.

Comment: I changed my x and y to my columns of my dataframe but the prediction is coming out way too big, it should be around 9k ad it 1.2 million is it aggregating? 1.2 might be the number for a whole year? @JuanR

Comment: can you upload your dataset somewhere so I can take a look a it?

Comment: Date Sales
1-1-2020 90404.71
2-1-2020 69904.71
3-1-2020 98934.112
4-1-2020 77084.43
5-1-2020 35877.42
6-1-2020 70217.37
7-1-2020 55346.05
8-1-2020 53787.852
9-1-2020 61244.56
10-1-2020 85195.13
11-1-2020 57514.52
12-1-2020 62368.108
@JuanR
It's not letting me format it very nice, but it just a date and a sales column for each month

Comment: @juge I updated my answer. Pay attention to the date formats! I am using `month-day-year` in this last example.

Comment: Thank you @JuanR

Answer (score 0):

Linear Regression needs your arrays to be of numeric type, since you have dates that are stored as strings in your `X` array, Linear Regression won't work as you expect.

You can convert the `X` array to numeric type by counting the number of days since the beginning date. You can try something like this in your DataFrame:

```
df.Date = (df.Date -  df.Date[0]).days
```

And then you can continue as you were doing.

I have assumed that the dates in your `Date` column are in the `datetime` format, else you would need to convert it first.